# How to detect an infinite loop in a recursive call?

Tags: java, detection, infinite-loop

I have a function that is recursively calling itself, and i want to detect and terminate if goes into an infinite loop, i.e - getting called for the same problem again. What is the easiest way to do that?

EDIT: This is the function, and it will get called recursively with different values of x and y. i want to terminate if in a recursive call, the value of the pair (x,y) is repeated.

```
int fromPos(int [] arr, int x, int y)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the function is purely functional, i.e. it has no state or side effects, then you could keep a `Set` of the arguments (edit: seeing your edit, you would keep a Set of pairs of (x,y) ) that it has been called with, and every time just check if the current argument is in the set. That way, you can detect a cycle if you run into it pretty quickly. But if the argument space is big and it takes a long time to get to a repeat, you may run out of your memory before you detect a cycle. In general, of course, you can't do it because this is the halting problem.

Comment: yeah, just realized its the halting problem. Maybe i should put a bounty on it. :D

Comment: This method does not detect if it is legal to for the function to sometimes call itself with the same values -- whereas the recursion depth method can work for the general case.

Comment: Oh, and it requires the overhead of constructing the set and the entries therein.

Comment: @BillyONeal: I said "if the function has no state or side effects" (I should also add "and does not depend on any external state"); in that case, it is not okay for a function to call itself with the same values

Answer (score 21):

One way is to pass a `depth` variable from one call to the next, incrementing it each time your function calls itself. Check that `depth` doesn't grow larger than some particular threshold. Example:

```
int fromPos(int [] arr, int x, int y)
{
    return fromPos(arr, x, y, 0);
}

int fromPos(int [] arr, int x, int y, int depth)
{
    assert(depth < 10000);

    // Do stuff

    if (condition)
        return fromPos(arr, x+1, y+1, depth + 1);
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would prefer if the method signature stays the same.

Comment: Just use overloading to provide a backward compatable signature.

Comment: In that case, you secretly call a 2nd function with the depth argument. See revised answer.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to find a work-around, because as you've asked it, there is no general solution.  See the [Halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way would be to implement one of the following:

Pass the previous value and the new value to the recursive call and make your first step a check to see if they're the same - this is possibly your recursive case.

Pass a variable to indicate the number of times the function has been called, and arbitrarily limit the number of times it can be called.

Answer (score 2):

You can only detect the most trivial ones using program analysis.  The best you can do is to add guards in your particular circumstance and pass a depth level context.  It is nearly impossible to detect the general case and differentiate legitimate use of recursive algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use overloading for a consistent signature (this is the better method), or you can use a static variable:

```
int someFunc(int foo)
{
    static recursionDepth = 0;
    recursionDepth++;
    if (recursionDepth > 10000)
    {
        recurisonDepth = 0;
        return -1;
    }
    if (foo < 1000)
        someFunc(foo + 3);
    recursionDepth = 0;
    return foo;
}
```

John Kugelman's answer with overloading is better beacuse it's thread safe, while static variables are not.

Billy3

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your method signature, you could keep a couple of sets to record old values of x and y.

```
static Set<Integer> xs;
static Set<Integer> ys;//Initialize this!
static int n=0;//keeps the count function calls.

int fromPos(int [] arr, int x, int y){

 int newX= getX(x);
 int newY= getY(y);
 n++; 
 if ((!xs.add(Integer.valueOf(newX)) && !ys.add(Integer.valueOf(newY))){

   assert(n<threshold); //threshold defined elsewhere.
   fromPos(arr,newx,newy);
 }
}
```

Comment: What about the case when its not getting repeated in the immediate next call but after some intervening calls?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be working on a 2D array. If you've got an extra bit to spare in the values of the array, you can use it as a flag. Check it, and terminate the recursion if the flag has been set. Then set it before continuing on.

If you don't have a bit to spare in the values, you can always make it an array of objects instead.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO Only loops can go into an infinite loop.

If your method has too many level of recursion the JVM will throw a StackOverflowError. You can trap this error with a try/catch block and do whatever you plan to do when this condition occurs.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function terminates in case a condition is fulfilled.

Examples:

- The result of a function is `0` or is `1`
- The maximum number of calls is reached
- The result is lower/greater than the input value

In your case the condition is `([x0,y0] == [xN,yN]) OR ([x1,y1] == [xN,yN]) OR ([xN-1,yN-1] == [xN,yN])`

`0, 1, ...N` are the indexes of the pairs

Thus you need a container(vector, list, map) to store all previous pairs and compare them to the current pair.

Answer (score 0):

First use mvn findbugs:gui to open a gui which point to the line where this error is present.

I also faced the same problem and I solved it by adding a boolean variable in the loop verification.

Code before ->

```
for (local = 0; local < heightOfDiv; local = local + 200) { // Line under Error
          tileInfo = appender.append(tileInfo).append(local).toString();
          while (true) {
            try {
              tileInfo = appender.append(tileInfo).append(getTheTextOfTheElement(getTheXpathOfTile(incr))).toString();
              incr++;
            } catch (Exception e) {
              incr = 1;
              tileInfo = appender.append(tileInfo).append("/n").toString();
            }
          }
```

To Solve this problem, I just added a boolean variable and set it to false in the catch block. Check it down

```
for (local = 0; local < heightOfDiv; local = local + 200) {
          tileInfo = appender.append(tileInfo).append(local).toString();
          boolean terminationStatus = true;
          while (terminationStatus) {
            try {
              tileInfo = appender.append(tileInfo).append(getTheTextOfTheElement(getTheXpathOfTile(incr))).toString();
              incr++;
            } catch (Exception e) {
              incr = 1;
              tileInfo = appender.append(tileInfo).append("/n").toString();
              terminationStatus = false;
            }
          }
```

This is how i Solved this problem.
Hope this will help. :)